# SQL Server 2016 & pyodbc - Login failed for user (18456)

Tags: sql-server, authentication, pyodbc

So have been smashing my head against a wall with this issue which I know is most likely a simple one to fix, but after spending a good day trawling the net cannot work out where I am going wrong.

I have an SQL server set up on my PC with a database called Stock_Controller_Main set up. I have also created a simple user called Jeff with permission and securable to the server and the database.

I can connect to the database with Server Manager Studio using Jeff and I can also connect with pyodbc when I use the trusted connection flags at the end of the connection string. But when I connect using the following!

```
    server = 'CLOWN-SHARK\TUCKER31 '
    database = 'Stock_Controller_Main'
    username = 'Jeff'
    password = 'password1'
    constring = ('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}; 
                  SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433; 
                  DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PDW='+password)
```

I get :

```
    pyodbc.Error: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'Jeff'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I have already been through all the post online and made sure that the server is set to both windows and SQL server authentication, and have Jeff set up as following!

[Server Roles Jeff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhhtV.png)

[Server User Mappings Jeff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddVxC.png)

I know this will be really simple fix but I can no longer see the wood through the trees!

And and all help is appreciated!

Comment: The connection string parameter name for "password" is `PWD`, not `PDW`.

Comment: Thank you!, I had just re-reviewed my code and my palm very quickly connected with my face multiple times!